# Android: failed to allocate memory

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to create an emulator with 2047 mb ram.
When I run it, I get this error:

```
[2011-02-22 14:24:14 - Emulator]
[2011-02-22 14:24:14 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2011-02-22 14:24:14 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
[2011-02-22 14:24:26 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8
```

I understand that lowering the number will make it work. But I'd rather have it with more ram, so I can test a game I'm developing. I'm assuming with more ram, it would run faster...

**Has anyone got 2047 mb of ram on the emulator? If so, how? What settings did you use? Did you change anything special on your computer?**

Using windows 7 64-bit, updated to the latest android sdk.  Also I have over 8gb of ram available. I do have one device (motorola milestone) to test on, however since it is a network-based game I need at least one other client (hoping to use the emulator) to run with in addition to my phone.

Comment: Haven't heard of Android devices with 2Gb RAM, so what's the point of making such an emulator?

Comment: As I mentioned above, I'm trying to run a game. I'm assuming allocating more ram would allow the game to run faster (ie render screen/send packes faster). If 2047mb of ram is unreasonable, I do not understand why the developers would allow it in the first place.

Comment: you can easily get rid of it check the my post 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/14851626/1461730

Comment: This worked for me - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7249408/1433187

Comment: @Egor I own an android with 2GiB. You sound like those guys who said noone would ever need 512k!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solution to running a faster emulator:

http://androiddevnotes.com/2011/03/08/1299521520000.html

Runs my game a lot faster, comparable to phone quality.

**-- Update 08/24/12 --**

I see that people still come here and comment on this answer, and I have done more research on this issue. I present to you the results of my findings.

***NOTE:** These tests were run on my computer, your computer may be different.*

1. Running an Android 2.2 (armeabi) emulator with Property 'Device ram size' = 2048 will
   fail, just as before
2. Running an Android 2.2 (armeabi) emulator with Property 'Device ram size' = 2048 **MB** will pass, **however** if you actually check the ram on the device, its around 128 MB.

   - check 1: Settings > Applications > Running Services - add all the numbers on the bottom of the screen
   - check 2: run the following  command in adb shell: `cat /proc/meminfo/` and note the **MemTotal** field
3. Running an Android 4.1 (armeabi-v7) emulator with Property 'Device ram size' = 2048 will work, **however** if you actually check the ram on the device its around 512 MB

   - check 1: Settings > Apps > Running tab - add all the numbers on the bottom of the screen
   - check 2: run the following  command in adb shell: `cat /proc/meminfo/` and note the **MemTotal** field
4. Running an Android 4.1 (armeabi-v7) emulator with Property 'Device ram size' = 2048 **MB** will work as well, but with the same results as 3.

**Conclusion**

Adding **'MB'** as noted in some of the comments below may allow your device to be launched, however it doesn't **actually** have 2 GB of RAM. Even with a 4.1 Emulator, the RAM Size is at 512 MB.

**Recommendation**

Please use an actual device for testing.

Comment: actually there are two reasons this could have happened.
1. you do not have enough RAM on local machine to assign to emulator
2. you did not put MB in value field for Device RAM ... if you write 512 it will fail 512MB will work etc

Comment: @grobartn 1. As I said in opening post, I have over 8 GB of RAM (12GB to be exact). 2. You can specify the Device RAM Size in the hardware properties. The description says the integer is in megabytes. ie. putting 'MB' is unecessary

Comment: fixed my issue and so far i have encountered so many cases where eclipse or android messed it up that i dont believe anything they say

Comment: Just commenting so people know, f20k is NOT correct, adding MB made my emulator work, thanks a lot @grobartn

Comment: In fact, MB is **unknown** to the emulator, making it fall back to a default value which is a lot lower. That's why it works. You could just as well write "foo".

Comment: I just want to let you know, the link in your answer is now dead

Answer (score 17):

I also get this error. Use RAM 512.

Comment: If you're looking for true emulator support with debugging, etc, this is the best method - just reduce your emulator ram and it'll stop crashing. On my macbook air with 4gb of ram, it ran fine with ram set to 1024, on my dell laptop from work running win7 with 4gb of ram - had to turn it down to 512...meh

Answer (score 13):

I was also getting this error message after upgrading my Android ADK Tool to 20 (even though I have more than sufficient RAM). No changes made to the 'Device RAM size' property helped (whether higher or lower, or with "MB").

What did work for me is running the emulator at the command line and specifying the RAM amount there (less than the default in my case); for example:

```
emulator -memory 512 -avd my_avd
```

Comment: this is the only way i can get my avd to run. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Add in Run Configurations window the parameter
**-memory 512**

See screenshot for reference

[image: Run Options]

Answer (score 5):

Solution is that you go and edit the config file for that perticuler avd in .android folder in your user folder in c drive 
with RAM = 1024 **MB** instead 1024

The problem is MB is not there...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but then figured it out. The problem was in the amount of ram I had specified for the virtual machine, and it was 1024MB by default, now I changed it to 512MB and it works; though my pc has 8GB of RAM.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but before I got the issue it asked me to capture a video source. I disabled the camera support and I was able to use 1024MB of RAM. Using Windows 64bit, Xoom (Android 3.0). i hope this helps for anyone with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the Device settings and change the RAM allocation to a lower number. If it was 1024 or More, reduce it to 512Mb or 256Mb.
You can Change it in "Edit Android Virtual Device (AVD)" dialog's Hardware Section --> Device ram size

Answer (score 1):

I changed my monitor's DPI settings from the launch options of AVD and syncronized it with the original and current setting of my monitor, and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting "failed to allocate memory: 8" errors as well. I have W7-64bit and 8GB of RAM. I found that by running AVD "as Administrator" the error disappeared, allowing the emulator to launch.

Answer (score 0):

Simple computer reboot helped me after I installed HAXM and got that error :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this Go to "Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager -> Chose your device -> Edit -> Advanced Settings -> Change the RAM parameter to 512 Mb.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what solved the problem for me

Credit goes to this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/17091571/10412027

Here's how to fix it and keep your desired amount of RAM:

Go into the AVD folder (example: C:\Users\username.android\avd\phone.avd)
Open the "config.ini" file in Wordpad.
Modify the 'partition' and 'ram' lines to end in "MB" (See below for the proper syntax changes)
ORIGINAL: disk.dataPartition.size=512M

MODIFIED: disk.dataPartition.size=512MB

ORIGINAL: hw.ramSize=1024

MODIFIED: hw.ramSize=1024MB

Save the file, and then run the emulator again (e.g. "emulator.exe -avd phone"). You must repeat this process for each of your AVDs.