# android emulator cannot start

Tags: android, emulation, adb

when I start a new emulator it comes this:

```
Failed to allocate memory: 8
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. 
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

how to repair it?

Answer (score 2):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969067/android-failed-to-allocate-memory) suggests that this problem occurs when you are using too much RAM.

Comment: I just use the default settings for RAM. How could it happen?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://droidsquad.blogspot.com/2011/04/android-virtual-device-avd-stopped.html) blog post suggests that you should lower the amount of RAM you allocated to your AVD.

Comment: I just use the default settings for RAM. How could it happen?

Comment: How much RAM do you have in your computer and how much is allocated to the AVD? Have you tried lowering it to see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: How to know how much RAM in my computer ? HOHO , forgive a noob.  @Glendon Trullinger

Comment: RAM/memory... If you run Windows, you can run dxdiag to check.  Just try lowering the RAM used by your AVD to 256MB or some number smaller than it is currently to see if it helps.  On my emulator, there is no "default" amount of memory.

Comment: I solved it. It depend on eclipse settings `-Xms128m -Xmx512m`

Comment: for additional info: check this link also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667907/android-emulator-failed-to-allocate-memory-8  it works for me

Answer (score 0):

As I mention here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14420779/1993898

I was able to fix this error by running AVD "as Administrator", therefore I believe this error to be related to filesystem permissions, or lack thereof.