# Android API 14, 15, 16 Emulators are not opening

Tags: android, android-emulator

I installed the API Level 14,15 & 16 and Created separate Emulators for each API's. When start the any of the `emulator` its just loading but not running. But when i run the API 16 it show message like as Follows

"Starting emulator for AVD '`JellyBeans`'
**Failed to allocate memory: 8
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information."** Error occuring

But API 8 and 10 all working perfectly.

Comment: check these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969067/android-failed-to-allocate-memory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222906/failed-to-allocate-memory-8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659033/android-emulator-cannot-start http://droidsquad.blogspot.in/2011/04/android-virtual-device-avd-stopped.html http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/152/topics/10683 refer these links it will solve your problem

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33930. You should report this problem on Android "bug tracking" page and not here.

Comment: As I mention here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14420779/1993898 ---------- I was getting "failed to allocate memory: 8" messages as well. I was only attempting to run an API 14 emulator, so I cannot verify appearance under other API's. I was able to fix this error by running AVD "as Administrator", therefore I believe that the issue may be tied to filesystem permissions, or lack thereof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only way is reduce your RAM size up to the emulator start.
Try with 512 MB not working, try with 256 MB not working, try with 128 MB.....
No other way to solve this problem.

So reducing the RAM is the solution for the problem. Also refer, I have posted the same issue in [google code](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40678&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) and got the solution in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7249408/1412308).

In the above link they all saying to try with the RAM size 512 MB but, I say reduce RAM size until it works.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue is to set Hardward acceleration. For some reason It was defaulted to Software everytime I make an edit and save. Hence I had to update it forefully in config.ini file

```
hw.gps=yes
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
hw.gpu.mode=host
```