# Android emulator failed to allocate memory 8

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I try to run my WXGA800 emulator from Eclipse it's giving an error like this

```
Failed to allocate memory: 8
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I checked the following links also

[Failed to allocate memory: 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222906/failed-to-allocate-memory-8)

[Android: failed to allocate memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969067)

I have tried reducing RAM size in emulator and increasing Java heapsize and ramsize but still I am facing the same error.

Comment: try setting the resolution manually instead use the built-in skin.

Comment: Please check out my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14420779/1993898

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to allocate memory: 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222906/failed-to-allocate-memory-8)

Comment: Cool. I worded this same question less eloquently and had people down vote it. I hope there is a great answer in here somewhere. I am trying to emulate the Samsung Galaxys with S-Pen support, and they are all exceeding the abilities of the emulator as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667907/android-emulator-failed-to-allocate-memory-8/11868277#11868277

Answer (score 410, accepted):

**Update**: Starting with Android SDK Manager version 21, the solution is to edit `C:\Users\<user>\.android\avd\<avd-profile-name>.avd\config.ini` and change the value

```
hw.ramSize=1024
```

to

```
hw.ramSize=1024MB
```

[image: Android 4.2 API 17]

The emulator is really slow, <del>hope they will release the intel images soon</del> use the new API17 Intel x86 images if you want to change it .. ([HAXM](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/), [Configuration](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/development-tools/haxm-speeds-up-the-android-emulator.html))

---

**Earlier Android SDK Manager releases:**

Had the same problem with the built-in WXGA800 skin. I got it working by editing the virtual device setup to:

- Target 4.0.3 API 15 / 4.1.0 API 16
- SD-card 300MiB
- Resolution 1280 x 800 (set manually -not the built-in ones)
- Device ram size 1024MB (with MB added to the number)
- Abstracted LCD 160

Here my tablet config for 4.1.0 API 16
`C:\Users\<user>\.android\avd\<avd-profile-name>.avd\config.ini`

```
hw.lcd.density=160
sdcard.size=300M
skin.path=1280x800
skin.name=1280x800
hw.cpu.arch=arm
abi.type=armeabi-v7a
hw.cpu.model=cortex-a8
vm.heapSize=48
hw.ramSize=1024MB
image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-16\armeabi-v7a\
```

This config shows the software keys too
[image: Screenshot Android 4.1 emulator 1280x800@160]

Comment: +1 I took this advice and then started the emulator from the command line to get this to work. Hope Xavier will save us from this flakeyness soon....

Comment: I made the error go away by reducing the "Memory Option: RAM" to 512 and setting SDcard Size to 300MiB.

Comment: I had the exact same problem with the Kindle Fire emulator. I only had to add "MB" to the hw.ramSize parameter to get it working. Increasing the heap size or RAM size wasn't necessary but doesn't hurt.

Comment: Mine got working after turning the RAM from 1024 to "1024**MB** (with MB added to the number)". Thx Lin-Art

Comment: adding MB fixed the memory issue but i am getting "unfortunately, system UI has stopped" error now :(

Comment: I read elsewhere that adding MB in the VDM to a device RAM will actually target the default RAM amount. Is this true?

Comment: Like in here http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html > Hardware options: Device ram size ?

Comment: This has worked for me. One thing I found is if I needed to make a change to the AVD later (e.g. add an SD card or turn on snapshot), the value for hw.ramsize is not in the dialog and you have to fill it in for the OK button to appear. By setting this back to 1024 (or whatever), you've rewritten the config.ini and you will need to manually modify it again.

Comment: Seriously, what a stupid bug... /facepalm
At least I can progress now! Thank you!

Comment: wow. this is terrible. the official SDK and testing kit doesn't properly handle this? you've got to edit .ini files by hand, and that's been the case for nearly a year? that is insane.

Comment: Very surprised that worked.  I guess because I am surprised that has been an unfixed bug this long.

Comment: What's the path on Mac?

Answer (score 67):

This following solution worked for me. In the following configuration file:

```
C:\Users\<user>\.android\avd\<avd-profile-name>.avd\config.ini
```

Replace

```
hw.ramSize=1024
```

by

```
hw.ramSize=1024MB
```

Comment: Not sure why but this fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Good spot, this must be a bug... I followed the files convention and just used an M, which also worked.

Comment: Kinda pathetic on Google's part, really. Do they not test?

Comment: +1 This works to me. Maybe it is because when I specified the ram size I select 1 GB.

Comment: In other answer somebody claimed that the "MB" is not actually recognised and changing from 1024 to 1024MB actually reduces the memory to 256MB which is default and therefore it starts working. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222906/failed-to-allocate-memory-8

Comment: It looks like after installing Android Studio I got all bugs possible. Thank you StackOverflow. This fix it.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, the solution was to change not only `config.ini` but also `hardware.ini` for the specific skin from `hw.ramSize=1024` to `hw.ramSize=1024MB`.

To find the `hardware.ini` file:

1. Open the `config.ini` and locate `skin.path`.
2. Then navigate to the folder where the android sdk is located.
3. Open the path, like this: `android-sdk\platforms\android-15\skins\WXGA720`.
4. Inside this folder you will locate the `hardware.ini`.
5. Change `hw.ramSize=1024` to `hw.ramSize=1024MB`.

Comment: worked for me. I don't know why people disliking your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Update: Starting with Android SDK Manager version 21, the solution is to edit C:\Users\.android\avd\.avd\config.ini and change the value

hw.ramSize=1024 
to

hw.ramSize=1024MB

OR

hw.ramSize=512MB

Answer (score 3):

This error fires if you set the AVD RAM to anything that is larger then the single largest block of continuous memory the emulator is able to allocate. Close anything RAM heavy, start your emulator, start everything else you need. In a previous answer I have limited this to x86 images with IntelHAXM, but this actually is the case for all types of emulator instances.

Answer (score 3):

In the AVD setup:
Change the CPU/ABI option to MIPS.
It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and what ended up being the issue was the RAM size: apparently 1024 (or whatever size) is different from 1024MB. Make sure you specify the units and it should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the ramSize in config.ini file didnt work for me.

I changed the SD Card size to 1000 MiB in Edit Android Virtual Device window ...It worked! :)

Comment: Are you sure your answer relates to the problem? Because the problem appears to relate to RAM, which is not going to change if one changes the SD card size.

Answer (score 0):

Go to edit Android Virtual Devices and change the 1024 Under Memory Options to 768. If it still doesn't work, keep going lower and lower.

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the RAM size in the AVD settings worked for me. The AVD being slow can eat up a lot of RAM, so keeping it at a minimum is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

For Skin remove No Skin and add some skin into it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Try this if other answers did not work for you.**

For me This happened for API 27 Emulator.

API 26 Emulator worked just fine. So I started API 26 Emulator first and then closed it.

Then I started API 27 Emulator and It worked with No errors at all.