# Problems with Android ADT Bundle. Failed to allocate memory: 8

Tags: 64-bit, emulation, bundle, adt, android-virtual-device

I am relitively new to Android development, but have been following a book, but I don't necessarily believe that my problem is, because of my experience level. Recently, Google updated to an Android ADT Bundle, which I thought was a wonderful idea, but I have been having some serious difficulties with virtual devices. I am on Windows 7 64bit and when I try to run a virtual device for instance the stock Galaxy Nexus values, I get an error screen reporting

```
Failed to allocate memory: 8
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

For the time being I am going back to not using the Bundle, but I really would like to know what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've provided too few details, but let me try as a telepathist...

 I think, this is an anwer to your question [Android emulator failed to allocate memory 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667907/android-emulator-failed-to-allocate-memory-8)

And even if it's not the answer, I don't think that you've already tried this [solution](http://bit.ly/STOHXo)

And even one more solution (which I use in case of AVD with high resolution). You may run your AVD from *.bat file, with following content:

```
cd C:\_my_folder\Android\android-sdk\tools
emulator-x86 @Intel_Android -memory 896
```