# Run Android project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I just started with my first Android app. In Eclipse, I made a new project `Hallo Android` and when I try to run without any changes, I get this message:

```
[2013-01-21 16:20:31 - Hallo Android] ------------------------------
    [2013-01-21 16:20:31 - Hallo Android] Android Launch!
    [2013-01-21 16:20:31 - Hallo Android] adb is running normally.
    [2013-01-21 16:20:31 - Hallo Android] Performing com.hurryapp.halloandroid.FirstActivity activity launch
    [2013-01-21 16:20:31 - Hallo Android] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'ICS_HVGA'
    [2013-01-21 16:20:31 - Hallo Android] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'ICS_HVGA'
    [2013-01-21 16:20:58 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8
    [2013-01-21 16:20:58 - Emulator] 
    [2013-01-21 16:20:58 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
    [2013-01-21 16:20:58 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

ADV is running. Please help.

Comment: Try out the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667907/android-emulator-failed-to-allocate-memory-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the following thread:
[Failed to allocate memory: 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222906/failed-to-allocate-memory-8)

Comment: great, thanks. Used the search but found nothing. Thanks Bro!

Comment: You welcome! if it helped you to find the solution, please set question as answered.