# How to allocate memory for android simulator more than 768M in windows?

Tags: android, memory, simulator

USING AVD if the ram exceeded 768M it will fail to allocate in windows. How to make it work for 2048M RAM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug. You have to edit the emulator's config file, the size itself from the emulator is ok.

Link: [Android emulator failed to allocate memory 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667907/android-emulator-failed-to-allocate-memory-8)