# Failed to allocate memory: 8 android

Tags: android, eclipse

i have installed eclipse and android sdk manager, installed files for android 4.22 in sdk and tried to run a sample android project.. but am getting the following error

```
 [2014-02-06 15:28:08 - myFirstApp] Android Launch!
 [2014-02-06 15:28:08 - myFirstApp] adb is running normally.
 [2014-02-06 15:28:08 - myFirstApp] Performing com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity activity launch
 [2014-02-06 15:28:08 - myFirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVD_233'
 [2014-02-06 15:28:08 - myFirstApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD_233'
 [2014-02-06 15:28:17 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8
 [2014-02-06 15:28:17 - Emulator] 
 [2014-02-06 15:28:17 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
 [2014-02-06 15:28:17 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

i tried the following..

```
 1)  accessed C:\Users\user\.android\avd\user.avd\config.ini and changed hw.ramSize=1024MB
 2)accessed avd and edited memory optionfrom 1024mb s to 512mb
```

its still not working...  thanks in advance..

Comment: Try [Android emulator failed to allocate memory 8][1] it would be helpful 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667907/android-emulator-failed-to-allocate-memory-8

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your RAM to 512 MB. It Worked for me..

If it is not working for you, Try reducing your RAM and VM heap further.

First try your emulator with some LDPI models(2.7 inch)..