# Unable to start any android sdk emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

it's really frustrating, i'm not able to start any emulator of the android sdk.
I've donwloaded the last android studio version along with the android sdk and installed it.

I played around with the RAM settings but it didn't help...
I tried all emulators, started the emulators from the ADV Manager and i tried to start the emulator via project run too. 
I select "Use Host GPU", but this didn't make a difference... I waited several hours, but nothing changes...

The emulator state is displayed as "Online", but the emulator display stays black and the android logo doesn't appear. In the ADB log the following line is displayed:

```
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device emulator-5554: device offline
```

I also tried adb kill-server and adb start-server as mentioned in other posts - doesn't help.

In the logcat following lines are displayed:

```
08-08 18:02:53.493  10169-10169/? W/iptables﹕ type=1400 audit(0.0:151): avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="ipt_TCPMSS" scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
08-08 18:02:53.743  10219-10219/? W/iptables﹕ type=1400 audit(0.0:152): avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="ipt_owner" scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
08-08 18:02:53.743  10219-10219/? W/iptables﹕ type=1400 audit(0.0:153): avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="ipt_owner" scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
08-08 18:02:53.743  10219-10219/? W/iptables﹕ type=1400 audit(0.0:154): avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="ipt_owner" scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
08-08 18:02:53.765  10017-10017/? E/BandwidthController﹕ runIptablesCmd(): res=1 status=256 failed /system/bin/iptables -A bw_INPUT -m owner --socket-exists
08-08 18:02:53.753  10220-10220/? W/ip6tables﹕ type=1400 audit(0.0:155): avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="ip6t_owner" scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
08-08 18:02:53.753  10220-10220/? W/ip6tables﹕ type=1400 audit(0.0:156): avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="ip6t_owner" scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
08-08 18:02:53.753  10220-10220/? W/ip6tables﹕ type=1400 audit(0.0:157): avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="ip6t_owner" scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
08-08 18:02:53.823  10017-10017/? E/BandwidthController﹕ runIptablesCmd(): res=1 status=256 failed /system/bin/ip6tables -A bw_INPUT -m owner --socket-exists
08-08 18:02:53.824  10224-10224/? E/logwrapper﹕ executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
08-08 18:02:53.825  10017-10017/? E/Netd﹕ failed to flush rules
08-08 18:02:53.826  10017-10017/? E/CommandListener﹕ failed to initialize RouteController (Remote I/O error)
08-08 18:02:53.838  10213-10213/? E/SurfaceFlinger﹕ hwcomposer module not found
08-08 18:02:53.839  10213-10213/? W/SurfaceFlinger﹕ no suitable EGLConfig found, trying a simpler query
08-08 18:02:53.839  10213-10213/? A/SurfaceFlinger﹕ no suitable EGLConfig found, giving up
08-08 18:02:53.839  10213-10213/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2, fault addr 0xb762b62c in tid 10213 (surfaceflinger)
08-08 18:02:53.938  10215-10215/? W/art﹕ Incomplete boot detected. Pruning dalvik cache
08-08 18:02:57.542  10239-10239/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/optimistic_dad: No such file or directory
08-08 18:02:57.542  10239-10239/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/optimistic_dad: No such file or directory
08-08 18:02:57.542  10239-10239/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/optimistic_dad: No such file or directory
08-08 18:02:57.542  10239-10239/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/sit0/optimistic_dad: No such file or directory
08-08 18:02:57.542  10239-10239/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default/use_optimistic: No such file or directory
08-08 18:02:57.544  10239-10239/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/eth0/use_optimistic: No such file or directory
08-08 18:02:57.544  10239-10239/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/lo/use_optimistic: No such file or directory
08-08 18:02:57.546  10239-10239/? E/Netd﹕ Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/sit0/use_optimistic: No such file or directory
08-08 18:02:58.283  10391-10391/? W/iptables﹕ type=1400 audit(0.0:158): avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="ipt_TCPMSS" scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
08-08 18:02:58.523  10438-10438/? W/iptables﹕ type=1400 audit(0.0:159): avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="ipt_owner" scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
08-08 18:02:58.523  10438-10438/? W/iptables﹕ type=1400 audit(0.0:160): avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="ipt_owner" scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
08-08 18:02:58.523  10438-10438/? W/iptables﹕ type=1400 audit(0.0:161): avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="ipt_owner" scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
08-08 18:02:58.584  10239-10239/? E/BandwidthController﹕ runIptablesCmd(): res=1 status=256 failed /system/bin/iptables -A bw_INPUT -m owner --socket-exists
08-08 18:02:58.573  10442-10442/? W/ip6tables﹕ type=1400 audit(0.0:162): avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="ip6t_owner" scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
08-08 18:02:58.573  10442-10442/? W/ip6tables﹕ type=1400 audit(0.0:163): avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="ip6t_owner" scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
08-08 18:02:58.573  10442-10442/? W/ip6tables﹕ type=1400 audit(0.0:164): avc: denied { module_request } for kmod="ip6t_owner" scontext=u:r:netd:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=system permissive=0
08-08 18:02:58.593  10239-10239/? E/BandwidthController﹕ runIptablesCmd(): res=1 status=256 failed /system/bin/ip6tables -A bw_INPUT -m owner --socket-exists
08-08 18:02:58.594  10443-10443/? E/logwrapper﹕ executing /system/bin/ip failed: No such file or directory
08-08 18:02:58.643  10239-10239/? E/Netd﹕ failed to flush rules
```

Over and over again....

And yes, i've also checked the HAXM and it is running:

```
C:\Users\VSYSM03\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\emulator.exe -avd x86_Nexus_S_API_22 -netspeed full -netdelay none
emulator: device fd:592
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
creating window 208 44 800 480
```

[image: My hardware]

Device configuration:

```
avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
AvdId=x86_Nexus_S_API_22
abi.type=x86
avd.ini.displayname=x86 Nexus S API 22
disk.dataPartition.size=200M
hw.accelerometer=yes
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.battery=yes
hw.camera.back=none
hw.camera.front=none
hw.cpu.arch=x86
hw.dPad=no
hw.device.hash2=MD5:37a2ff6e511626ba3ceddec8264474be
hw.device.manufacturer=Google
hw.device.name=Nexus S
hw.gps=yes
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
hw.initialOrientation=landscape
hw.keyboard=yes
hw.lcd.density=240
hw.mainKeys=yes
hw.ramSize=768
hw.sdCard=yes
hw.sensors.orientation=yes
hw.sensors.proximity=yes
hw.trackBall=no
image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-22\default\x86\
runtime.network.latency=none
runtime.network.speed=full
runtime.scalefactor=auto
sdcard.path=C:\Users\VSYSM03\.android\avd\x86_Nexus_S_API_22.avd\sdcard.img
skin.dynamic=yes
skin.name=nexus_s
skin.path=C:\Program Files\Android\Android     Studio\plugins\android\lib\device-art-resources\nexus_s
snapshot.present=no
tag.display=Default
tag.id=default
vm.heapSize=32
```

And here a picture, how the emulator looks like, there is no graphic update - nothing...

[image]

Has anyone an idea? I'm playing around one week....

thanks mario

Comment: Have you tried adding MB to hw.ramSize? As in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667907/android-emulator-failed-to-allocate-memory-8

Comment: What does the console say (not log cat)?

Comment: @adelphus thanks, but doesn't help

Comment: @mttdbrd console? do you mean, wehen starting avf from console? then it prints the same, "hax working...", "creating window..."... window appears shortly, but then the window hangs, no android logo is displayed...

Comment: OK. I think we need to see some code.

Comment: Code? With "window" i mean the emulator window... The emulator also doesn't start without an project of Android Studio. When i start a device directly from avd manager of the android sdk, the emulator also hangs without android logo appearing