# Error Message: emulator-arm.exe has stopped working

Tags: android, mobile, android-emulator

I have been having issues running my first android app. Yesterday, i came close to running it but my happiness was dashed when i encountered this error:

```
emulator-arm.exe has stopped working
```

What do i do? I want to run this 'Hello World'

My Console Display:

```
[2011-07-28 10:46:52 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-07-28 10:46:52 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-07-28 10:46:52 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.bestvalue.hello.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2011-07-28 10:46:52 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'my_avd' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2011-07-28 10:46:52 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_avd'
[2011-07-28 10:47:13 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentred
[2011-07-28 10:47:13 - Emulator] 
[2011-07-28 10:47:14 - HelloAndroid] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-07-28 10:47:14 - HelloAndroid] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-07-28 10:47:28 - HelloAndroid] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.bestvalue.hello.HelloAndroid activity launch'!
```

Comment: have used a pc health/ registry cleaner; nothing changed

Comment: so you installed the sdk and just created a new project and it doesnt run... have you tried creating a new emulator with different size?

Comment: Try allocating different (most likely lower) amount of RAM for your emulated device. In Eclipse: Window/AVD Manager then select your device, then Edit now set the Device ram size in hardware. U want as much as possible, so it will work faster. 1Gb is good but may cause that error.

Answer (score 46):

Change the resolution of the device and it should work. It didn't work for me when the resolution was 1280X800. I changed it to 800X600 and it worked fine.

Comment: i changed the hvga to default in android sdk and avd manager and it helps.

Comment: I also "changed the hvga to default in android sdk and avd manager and it helps". Thanks a lot!

Comment: Mittal Patel it worked for me also. Thanks. I was trying to [using bundle of ] start the emulator of 7 inch with resolution 1024*640 but when it crash. When I used 10 inch emulator it is working fine. I don't know whats the reason.

Comment: Doesn't work. Also, what kind of device are you using that starts with a 1280 x 800? That is a monitor's resolution, not a phone's....

Comment: it works for me, thanx! I decrease the resolution to 480 x 800)

Answer (score 34):

After many attempts to fix, I found the following most helpful: [Android: failed to allocate memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969067/android-failed-to-allocate-memory)
 Running the emulator with 512mb of ram or less seems to be the only solution so far for me. Thanks

Comment: It worked. Was trying to add Galaxy Nexus virtual device. Changed from default 1024 to 512mb. Nothing else changed.

Answer (score 29):

Here's how to fix it and keep your desired amount of RAM:

1. Go into the AVD folder (example: C:\Users\username\.android\avd\phone.avd)
2. Open the "config.ini" file in Wordpad.
3. Modify the 'partition' and 'ram' lines to end in "MB" (See below for the proper syntax changes)

ORIGINAL: disk.dataPartition.size=512M

MODIFIED: disk.dataPartition.size=512MB

ORIGINAL: hw.ramSize=1024

MODIFIED: hw.ramSize=1024MB

Save the file, and then run the emulator again (e.g. "emulator.exe -avd phone"). You must repeat this process for each of your AVDs.

Comment: <drive-letter>:\Users\<username>\.android\avd\<phone-name>.avd\ ;)

Comment: This should be the top answer among all

Answer (score 4):

Might be old question but try executing directly from command line, assuming you are in `android-sdk\tools`folder run your created emulator by calling `emulator-arm @youremulatorname`

Comment: I give you the credit because I can see the emulator, but I don't see my app being loaded

Answer (score 3):

After some minutes searching Google and eventually Stackoverflow I finally came across a fix. Only way for reliably generate the crash during my experimentation was changing RAM size to 128 and in fact, many crashes depend on 2 problem:

- PC Ram is less or equal to one defined in AVD. You must set it lower depending on your hardware RAM.
- Also, some graphic and OpenGL issues found that can be fixed by changing default display to HVGA or setting a lower resolution in AVD.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

emulator-arm.exe is not working due dual graphic card. select the basic graphical card not high performance one and is going to work. I have nvidia 555M and as bases Intel. Using intel the emulator starts.

Answer (score 1):

i found tht using the avd manager to delete and recreate the virtual device without checking the snapshot enabled check box while creating the avd works. i found this on google group for android. although this issue hasnt been resolved, this method can be used as a workaround for this problem until this bug is fixed

Answer (score 1):

Two options worked for me:
1. Changing the emulator resolution. I don't know why, but if I change it, it just works.
2. Changind the "Number of emulated web cameras" variable to 0 in AVD.

Thank you very much for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Marking "Use Host GPU" checkbox worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see an emulator running, check Task Manager to see if you have an `emulator-arm` process already running. If there is an `emulator-arm` process, select it, choose "End Process", and try again.

Answer (score 0):

My case was that the skin setting somehow had been changed from **WVGA800** to **WVGA854** in AVD. After I switch it back, the emulator works.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this for me after trying all the options above. There is a solution at [AndroidDevelopers](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/DSi3oAuNnS7) on Google Plus.

> If you want to have graphics acceleration enabled by default for this
>   AVD, in the Hardware section of the AVD configuration, click New,
>   select GPU emulation and set the value to Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window->Open Prespective->DDMS

you will see view as mention below

[image]

click on the portion i have highlighted and click on reset adb,and try to run your project again

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to set memory RAM from 1907 (default) to 512 to get it working

Answer (score 0):

Use a low resolution device, when I selected `Nexus 4` it kept running smoothly with me.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth checking that HAXM is installed/enabled (this fixed issue for me, without it got same error as you were reporting and it slowed my Mac to a crawl).

Answer (score -1):

Just rebooting my PC worked for me.