# emulator-arm crashes on using cdma command in telnet

Tags: android, telnet

If i enter cdma command in telnet it crashes..

The configuration used by me is
API Level 14
Ram 511MB

Galaxy Nexus: 4.65" 720*1280

I  have tried reducing the Ram and Resolution 
I have also tried modifying the config.ini file mentioned in
[Error Message: emulator-arm.exe has stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855877/error-message-emulator-arm-exe-has-stopped-working)

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

The emulator is very buggy in my opinion. My advice is to either use a physical device or try this https://www.manymo.com