# Process isn't responding Android studio emulator

Tags: android-studio

Everytime I run the android studio, it gives me the error message `"Process isn't responding"`  I am so confused, since yesterday emulator worked good. But today suddenly it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try changing RAM size and resolution of your emulator and you should decrease them .
see this page : [Error Message: emulator-arm.exe has stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855877/error-message-emulator-arm-exe-has-stopped-working)