# Process system isn't responding in android emulator

Tags: android-studio

When I starts android emulator in android studio ; after boot completes this window opens :
[image]

and emulator hangs . How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found some solutions in this page :
[Error Message: emulator-arm.exe has stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855877/error-message-emulator-arm-exe-has-stopped-working)

In this page suggests changing of resolution and RAM and you should decrease them.
When I decrease my resolution It fixes this problem .

Answer (score 15):

In my case, **cold reboot** resolves the issue on an OSX machine.

- Close all open emulator first
- Open android studio **configure > avd manager**
- from the virtual device you are working on **action > cold boot now**

[image]

Hope the interface will be almost similar to Linux and Windows machine and the fix will workout there too.

Comment: I even added cold boot as default by going to edit of a particular avd -> Advanced Options -> Cold boot as default

Answer (score 4):

Try to use a low-resolution device, when I selected Nexus 4 it kept running smoothly with me. If it doesn't work. try this:

If you want to have graphics acceleration enabled by default for this AVD, in the Hardware section of the AVD configuration, click New, select GPU emulation and set the value to Yes.

Answer (score 3):

Beyond other possible solutions, what worked to me was to change the "Emulated performance" option to "Software".

Answer (score 1):

I have tried changing the resolution, RAM size, Emulated performance graphic type, etc.. but none of them worked. Finally, I found that the android version image was my problem(Android P) so I downloaded a different version image and it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

If the virtual device was previously working, try to wipe user data.
Go to the AVD manager, select the virtual device action and click on "Wipe data" (Wipe the user data of this AVD)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I fixed it:

In the AVD Manage-> Create Virtual Device... -> New Hardware Profile

- Device Name: My Device
- Resolution 800 x 600
- RAM: 512 MB
- Left other options as default -> Finish
  Next -> Next (Or select API e.g R) -> Finish

That device never throws that error and works faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing cold reboot from Android Studio. It'll work normally then. I guess it usually happens when your PC/laptop goes into sleep mode, with emulator, debugger running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

**Decrease API level** resolves the issue on an Windows machine.

**Solution 2:**

Try to use a low-resolution device, If it doesn't work. try this:

If you want to have graphics acceleration enabled by default for this AVD, in the Hardware section of the AVD configuration, click New, select GPU emulation and set the value to Yes.

**Solution 3:**

**Follow Steps:**

1. Go to Device Manager

[image]

2. Select Wipe Data

[image]

3. Launch AVD again