# How to make Emulator respond in an android studio for the first time start up

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm a beginner in Android Studio, I want to run my "Hello World!" on the emulator, the emulator start and shows the screen of the phone but the phone isn't responding.
As shown in the below picture

[image: The screenshot of my emulator]

I've waited for about 5 hours but is still the same thing, I also tried to close the emulator and run it again but It's still the same. The Emulator is the one that came along with the Android Studio. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: have you tried deleting emulator and create a new one?

Comment: Did you modify the code? or is it the default project code from a new project?

Comment: It's the default code

Answer (score 2):

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43779596/process-system-isnt-responding-in-android-emulator) you probably need to fix some settings before you the emulator. Also try updating android studio especially android avd manager. Restart and then run emulator again

- Running the emulator with 512mb of ram or less might be a solution
- Changing the resolution of the device may also work

Open AVD manager

[image]

Create New Virtual Device

[image]

And then pick resolution you want. Recommended 480X800

[image]

In advanced settings you can change ram memory of emulator

[image]

Comment: Okay but like which settings do I need to fix? and how can I update the avd manager?

Comment: try changing resolution first