# 'could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB' for Android Emulator

Tags: opengl-es, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Actually I have a problem with my Android application in eclipse. When I run my program, it gives me a message which is concluded of many errors.
So I copied and pasted them here to show you what is the exact problem with the emulator. Any ideas?

```
Starting emulator for AVD 
Failed to create Context 0x3005
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
```

Comment: Get this error too. I'm trying to launch Android 4.0.3 emulator - useless.

Comment: Is the emulator starting anyway or crashing? If it's crashing, is that all the errors or do you get a 'Failed to allocate memory' error as well? If so, it seems to be a Google bug and some fixes here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222906/failed-to-allocate-memory-8

Comment: I am getting the exact problem. Did you fix it somehow?

Answer (score 6):

Try setting the RAM to 512 Mb. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It may be too late to answer this question,but I solved the problem (`could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB`) by installing the latest version of my graphics (video) driver.
also from device properties, I have checked '`use host GPU`' option. it is working now with the following settings: 
[image: settings for virtual device]

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your graphic card driver

Answer (score 0):

Graphics acceleration for the emulator takes advantage of your development computer's graphics hardware, specifically its graphics processing unit (GPU), to make screen drawing faster. To use the graphics acceleration feature, you must have the following versions of the Android development tools installed:

```
Android SDK Tools, Revision 17 or higher
Android SDK Platform API 15, Revision 3 or higher
```

Please check this link http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly edge case but my emulator started fine when I was physically at the computer that ran it *but* when I remoted into that computer (via RDP) and attempted to start the emulator, it failed with these errors.

I believe this is a limitation with the emulator software over remote connections because I went to the physical location of the computer and started the emulator and it worked fine.