# Android Simple App

Tags: java, android, netbeans

I have some problems with the Android developing of applications. I installed the latest SDK from their site, and also I installed the plug-in for NetBeans IDE 7.4, both with no problems. I tried to make a simple app to try to see if it works. I made an emulator for Android 4.4.2. When I run the simple app made (I created the project, and made no modifications), I get this output on the Android development: Package deployment failed with: Unknown failure. and also this on the Android emulator: could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB, for 8 times. I tried to make some changes already proposed on this site, with no effects.

What should I do? Thank you!

The code source from the mainActivity is:

```
package com.android.androidapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.main);
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest?

Comment: Are you able to run any of the sample applications included in the Android Developer Toolkit? If not, you have a configuration error and probably need to reinstall something.

Comment: Is that `\`enter code here\`` really in your source? It shouldn't be there. It is just a hint that you should enter your own code at that point, to make your Activity do something useful.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407501/android-emulator-could-not-get-wglgetextensionsstringarb-error


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328344/could-not-get-wglgetextensionsstringarb-for-android-emulator

Comment: the enter code part isn't in the source. I just tried one new app, with the code included automatically.

Comment: I tried the possible duplicate exaplanations, with no results

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolved it by activating the android plugin in Netbeans.
To do so, go to 
`tools -> plugins -> installed`
then check the show details checkbox and search for the android plugins then activate them.