# I am Unable to run android WXGA720 emulator

Tags: android

Have to run Android XHDPI: ( Samsung Galaxy S III ) sized emulator in my eclipse environment.

I have done the following settings.

Target: Google APIs (Google Inc) - API Level 15

SD Card: size: 1024mb

Skin:  Built In: WXGA720

Hardware:  Abstracted LCD Density: 320

```
        VM application heap size: 48

        Device ram size: 1024
```

The emulator is not running any ideas please.?

Comment: Without the error message, we can just guess that the problem lies somewhere in your computer...

Comment: i have read some post. it says the wxga720 emulator will work with only Rev.16.
My environment is already updated with Rev.20.
How to make run Rev.16 again. or any other suitable solutions.

Comment: Even then, posting the error message you get will be useful for users that are searching for an answer with that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often have this problem, i have 8gb of ram avalible and still it does not accept 1gb of ram for the emulator. Did you try to change the ram value to 512 for example? Because that's  working for me.

Another solution often used is setting the screen dimensions manual, so not using the presets like WXGA720.

See this topic: [Failed to allocate memory: 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222906/failed-to-allocate-memory-8)

Answer (score 1):

As I mention here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14420779/1993898

If your error was "failed to allocate memory: 8", I was able to fix this error by running AVD "as Administrator".