# AVD Emulator error

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

When I try to run my app on the AVD it shows the following error although it was running fine two days back

```
[2013-03-05 09:54:32 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8
[2013-03-05 09:54:32 - Emulator] 
[2013-03-05 09:54:32 - Emulator] This application has requested the R u n t i m e to   terminate it in an unusual way.
[2013-03-05 09:54:32 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Please help.

Comment: did you allocate memory when you created your avd?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222906/failed-to-allocate-memory-8 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969067/android-failed-to-allocate-memory