# what's wrong with this android virtual device

Tags: android, emulation

i have several AVDs defined on eclipse and they are working fine.

i just added a Galaxy Nexus (4.65" 720x1280) and used the default setting, RAM-1024 VMheap 64
Internal 200MB , no SD card.

i get a launch error

```
[2013-03-07 10:57:17 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8
[2013-03-07 10:57:17 - Emulator] 
[2013-03-07 10:57:17 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
```

I've tried playing with memory sizes and such but nothing helps

I'm running on win7 with 4GB ram

my pc screen res is 1920x1200

any ideas anyone?

thx steve

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222906?

Comment: Probably the same problem as in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222906/failed-to-allocate-memory-8)

Comment: try to decrease the ram size from 1024 to 512.

Answer (score 0):

please delete all other avd and try your galaxy nexus avd. I think if we create so many avd we got this type of memory issue. and also decrease the ram size.

Comment: i just deleted all my AVDs, went to the device definition panel, chose 'Galaxy Nexus by Google', got and AVD called 'AVD_for_Galaxy_Nexus_by_Google'. when i tried to run it i got the same thing: Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD_for_Galaxy_Nexus_by_Google'
[2013-03-07 14:56:13 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: