# Device Emulator launching error

Tags: android, android-emulator, device

I am new to Android. I create a small app by seeing android site but when I run the app I am getting fallowing error for device emulator .

```
[2014-02-14 15:47:59 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8
[2014-02-14 15:47:59 - Emulator] 
[2014-02-14 15:47:59 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2014-02-14 15:47:59 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

can any one please help me in this?

Comment: Do you have android SDK installed properly?

Comment: yes . . I downloaded from android site . . adt bundle . . & I openned Eclipse create layout and create emulator after I run the program . .I got those error . .

Comment: what is your system ram size installed?

Comment: Normally to dealing with Eclipse IDE you must have atleast 4 GB of ram.

Comment: @Brendon : Is it so? I have a 2gb RAM system. Even I have used Eclipse in a 1 GB RAM system also. what say?

Comment: Eclipse will getting open even in a 512mb ram, instead if you need a good performance while creating projects it needs 4Gb ram, yes its possible at 1Gb ram only if u r not multi tasking many applications.. Learn Memory allocations and you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means you are allowing your emulator to use too much memory, relative to the amount your computer has or is using. 
To solve it, open your AVD manager, select the emulator and click Edit, and change the RAM to a smaller number.

See here : [Failed to allocate memory: 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222906/failed-to-allocate-memory-8?rq=1)

Comment: k . . after it starts how to run a program . . pls help me . .

Comment: Wait till it boots, it takes a while. Be patient.

Comment: You project will automatically run after emulator online if you run the project by right click on your project folder and Click Run As - > Android Application.

Comment: k . . but in a site they have mentioned that , unlock the emulator . how to do it . .

Comment: just like a mobile, did you ever before used android mobiles?