# Android emulator not running with 2G RAM

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to launch the Android emulator on a PC with 16GB RAM (Windows 8 x64) with the following settings:

```
Abstacted LCD Density: 240
Max VM application heap: 24
Device ram size: 2048
```

When I try to start the emulator, I get an error:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'Android_4.0_1024'
emulator: WARNING: Requested RAM size of 2048MB is too large for your environment, and is reduced to 1152MB.
Failed to allocate memory: 8
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I run the emulator with more than 1 GB RAM?

Thanks in advance,
Ivan

Comment: Here is an answer on your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/6884186/1548085

Answer (score 0):

Win64 is a good start.

Did you happen to install a 64-bit JDK?

PS:

Windows 7/64 works great with 64-bit JDK's.  I have zero experience with Windows 8 and any Java, so I can't help you there...

Comment: Yep.
java version "1.6.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: OK - then define some runtime switches (-Xmx, -Xss, etc etc).  And, AFAIK, the Android SDK is exclusively Win32.  But, IIRC, you can still fully exploit a 64-bit address space for your emulator: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html