# How to make an AVD with > 768MB RAM To emulate Galaxy devices

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator, galaxy

I am trying to emulate the Galaxy Note 2 which contains 2GiB RAM and some custom hardware like the s-pen and TouchWiz. I created an emulator with 2GB to start with. The emulator won't launch, in fact it is crashing eclipse. I would also like to emulate multi-screen TouchWiz support. I don't see any info anywhere on emulating custom platforms like TouchWiz.  Any ideas? I need a decent testing platform for the Galaxy series, but I can't even get basic android working.

edit: The Samsung dev page shows this setup: http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/emulator-size-for-galaxy-note-2-/77/178557

Is this a lack of available ram?

Comment: Why the down votes? I need to do this to test my program on a realistic device. Does anyone who voted understand my question? The built-in emulator seems to cap out at 768MB

Comment: This is a very open-ended question, and the wording includes a second topic of emulating TouchWiz.  That's why it was downvoted. More details are necessary to understand any hint of your crashing.

Comment: @TomPace I never even got to the TouchWiz portion of the project because the emulator choked on the 2GiB ram requirement. The reason I included it is because it is essential to emulating Samsung's platform.

Comment: I added an up-vote because I've gone through the pains of Android and Eclipse development and crashing. I found a SO question that may provide your solution, but of course, in Android development, a solution that works for 10 people may still not work for the odd-one-out, and it's way more time-consuming and difficult to find out why, than Xcode/iOS.

Answer (score 3):

using the suggestion of manually adding "mb" behind the memory size in your configuration file (as suggested in this thread: [Android: failed to allocate memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969067/android-failed-to-allocate-memory) ) (located at: %USERPROFILE%/.android/avd/name-of-your-avd/config.ini) has solved the 768mb problem here!

example that now works on my win7 x64 ultimate os -with- dedicated gpu;

```
avd.ini.encoding=ISO-8859-1
hw.sdCard=no
hw.device.manufacturer=Google
hw.mainKeys=no
hw.lcd.density=320
hw.accelerometer=yes
hw.dPad=no
hw.cpu.arch=x86
skin.name=720x1280
abi.type=x86
hw.device.hash=1197498893
hw.trackBall=no
hw.device.name=Galaxy Nexus
hw.camera.back=none
hw.sensors.proximity=yes
hw.battery=yes
disk.dataPartition.size=512M
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-18\x86\
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.sensors.orientation=yes
hw.camera.front=none
hw.gps=yes
skin.dynamic=yes
skin.path=720x1280
hw.keyboard=yes
vm.heapSize=128
hw.ramSize=2048mb
```

I have tested this on two machines, my desktop and laptop both running Windows 7 X64 Ultimate

The Laptop has an Intel I7-4702MQ with 12GB ram and GeForce GTX765M
The Desktop has an Intel I7-3820 with 32GB ram and has Ati 6950 in Crossfire and an Nvidia GTX560Ti (normally for physx).

The desktop only has issues in reliably starting the gpu acceleration while using crossfire, other then that i've had no issues with the emulator at all and even managed to assign 4096mb RAM with a 256VM Heap (however increasing the VM-heap above 128 seems to slowdown emulator initiation tremendously here)

On the desktop i also tested the 4096MB setup while even using a RAMDISK but this didn't increase performance too much.

Best settings overall (in my experience) in startup and responsiveness after just a few tests;
2048 with 128mb VM Heap size, gpu acceleration enabled.

Hope this helps out others!

Answer (score 1):

I actually had a similar problem when running on Windows 7.  When I relaunched Android studio with administrator privileges it worked.  Otherwise I couldn't even open the AVD manager.

Comment: This might be it. I hadn't thought of running it like that, as I only elevate to admin. This may solve more than one problem. +1

Answer (score 0):

This question may be a duplicate of:

[Android: failed to allocate memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969067/android-failed-to-allocate-memory)

I don't presume you would NOT do this, but I'm just going to say it anyway...
Check the details of the correct answer, but especially check the comments for the correct answer.

Seriously, I hope this helps.  Android and Eclipse issues have been a problem for me in the past until I learned to crush them with a Zen-like attitude and much exhaustive research and trial-and-error.

Comment: I didn't even try to figure out the quad-core or GPU :) The best answer there is use 512 and suck it up. Seriously!?

Comment: @SinthiaV I could keep doing research on this for an hour or two, but I'm going to stop here.  It's an interesting problem you're having, and I'd love to help more, but I need sleep. Android is a good system, much more open than iOS of course, but I'm familiar with both, and iOS has much higher stability and ease-of-development.  Android is of course free, and has a lot of interesting features to be exploited.  Good luck!!